# Selenium not working on Gcp Python Virtual Environment

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to start a new Chrome browser session using Google Cloud Platform.
Firstly, i set up a new environment (not using "sudo" command, as i am not the root user, since there are 2 more users with me using the Google Virtual Machine).

Then I downloaded a Chromedriver (version 108 as the Chrome version on the VM), and i made it esecutable by using the "chmod a+x" command.

After that i tried starting this simple script, named "prova.py":

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
d = webdriver.Chrome('/home/mattiasospetti5/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
d.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

With the following command `python prova.py` i got the following error:

```
File "/home/mattiasospetti5/tutorial-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 106, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/mattiasospetti5/tutorial-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 288, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/mattiasospetti5/tutorial-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 381, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/mattiasospetti5/tutorial-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/mattiasospetti5/tutorial-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I really don't know what to do, I searched a lot online on this forum, but nothing seems like working.

Answer (score 1):

The [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) Driver Manager is configured/optimized for special cloud environments such as GCP. `pip install seleniumbase`, and then run with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="chrome", headless=False)
driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.quit()
```

For headless mode, use this script:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="chrome", headless=True)
driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.quit()
```

There are a lot more options besides `browser` and `headless`.

You can also use the SeleniumBase `SB()` context manager:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(browser="chrome", headless=True) as sb:
    sb.open("https://google.com")
```

SeleniumBase has [its own API](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/method_summary.md), if you use that format. Other formats exist too.

Plenty of SeleniumBase tutorials for Google Cloud, [such as this one](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/integrations/google_cloud/ReadMe.md).

Comment: The SeleniumBase context manager is the better way to go for this, as it will also start `Xvfb` as needed, which allows you to spin up a regular browser in a headless environment. I can't guess if your environment is already using that.